# Why SpringBoot example doesn't work like this?

Tags: spring, annotations, http-status-code-404, spring-boot

So there is an example from the Spring web-site:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

which works fine. There are notes `@RestController` is `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody` and The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.

My question is: **Why is there 404 error** accessing "/" if I use annotations below?

```
@ResponseBody
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example { ... }
```

Comment: No the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation isn't equivalent of that. It is intended for testing to indicate that the test case needs to bootstrap Spring Boot as well..

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is new in 1.2 and it is equivalent to `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`. To indicate that a test should bootstrap boot use `@IntegrationTest`

Comment: @M.Deinum: that text is copied from here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: You are right, I was confusing the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` with this. The `@SpringBootApplication` is a new addition which indeed should work as you state. Although (as the answer states) you where missing the `@RestController` or `@Controller` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `@ResponseBody` annotation alone isn't enough to tell Spring that your class is a MVC controller. You either need to use `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example { ... }
```

or `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`:

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <artifactId>quick-log</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.quick</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

#### main function

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApiController {


    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

easy to work~

you can find some quick and simple sample in github like this

https://github.com/vector4wang/spring-boot-quick